# react-konva resize anchors not shown outside canvas

Tags: reactjs, react-konva

I am trying to get react-konva to work similar as to what [canva](https://www.canva.com/en_gb/) is. Having a canvas for a certain size and when I add an image, which is larger than the canvas, it should show me the resize anchors outside of the canvas, but it doesn't. It seems to clip the image at the borders of the canvas.

Can it even be done with react-konva to show the anchors outside the canvas to resize an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting here the solution I found, pointed in the direction by @lavrton.

So if anyone else needs this, please have a look.

[codesandbox.io/s/dry-paper-fmpn58?file=/src/App.jsx](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-paper-fmpn58?file=/src/App.jsx)

Answer (score 1):

`react-konva` or `konva` can't render anything outside the canvas element. To resolve the issue, you can create a large canvas and render "background" and "page content" as part of the main canvas. To cut content by page size you can do the following:

1. Draw gray background of the canvas
2. Create a group and put all "page" content into it
3. Use clipping on the group to cut content to the page
4. Put transformer on top of the group

As an alternative, instead of using a group with a clip, you can put semi-transparent shape with a hole in it.

[image]

Comment: Hi @lavrton, thanks. I only am not able to get the transformer handles outside the group like that. I've tried to add the transformer above the Group, but its not showing the handles.

Comment: @udarts hard to say without demo. It should work ok.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, here is a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-paper-fmpn58?file=/src/App.jsx, click and drag the red box and you see the transformer anchors disappear behind the grey area.

Comment: @udarts that is because the transformer is placed near rectangle. As I meantioned in the answer, you need to put transformer of top of all content. It may be better to place it in the parent App component as the last canvas element.

Comment: I've added a Transformer above the Group, but each element in the group (in this case the Rectangle component, not the Rect) has a Transformer as well to be able to transform that element. Can you otherwise provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: do u have an update?

Comment: @udarts I mean remove Transformer from Rectangle component and use just one globar transformer that is placed above all content. Or you can try to use Portal component from react-konva-utils to put Transformer in a different parent.

Comment: Does this also work the same if you have multiple items inside that group, e.g.: multiple rectangles?

Comment: I managed to get it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-paper-fmpn58?file=/src/App.jsx